# Print method "invalid syntax" reversing a string

Tags: python, printing

Trying to reverse a string in python and can't figure out what is wrong with my program that this is seen as invalid syntax.

````
print(r)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```
````

Thanks so much here is my code.

```
s = "Hello! my name is MangoKitty"
r = ''.join(reversed(s.split(''))
print(r)
```

Comment: you have syntax error: you are missing one ')' in r = ''.join(reversed(s.split('')))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are missing `)` at the end of second line.
2. You are using empty separator `s.split('')`

Answer (score 0):

To reverse the string you can do:

```
s[::-1]
```

Comment: This is cool. What is the logic behind as i can see in my console it works but not sure how!

Comment: You can use this [link](https://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/) to see the logic. It is under the header "Skipping character while splitting Python strings".